# Can anyone tell me how to totally get rid of Unity in Ubuntu properly?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

Yeah, that's what I want to do - Get rid of unity and properly. I don't want to throw the all new design(icons and all) away though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why remove Unity, install [new Window Managers](http://www.dragonblogger.com/desktop-windows-managers-unity-ubuntu/) !

Answer to your actual question is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity).

Comment: Here's a question I have -  I installed gnome 3 in ubunutu alright but I don't want that white top in the windows, I want ubuntu's original top with the pretty icons in it. How do I get that?

Comment: @alvasrawuther This makes it look like good old ubuntu http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed/

Comment: Oh so I'll have to wait till the release of Ubuntu 12.04 then, so I guess!...and um thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Somebody did it already and wrote down steps:
http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-remove-unity-and.html

Comment: This does really help too.

Comment: Please include the relevant steps here. Answers with links only are not considered real answers.

Comment: You mods can copy/paste, licence of original article allows it.

Comment: I'm not a diamond moderator, just a regular user. It's actually not a matter of copy-pasting, but summarizing and outlining the most important steps if ever the blog goes offline (which happens quite often). Your decision if you want to or not, but answers with just links are often downvoted, flagged for deletion, or generally looked down upon. Just saying.